# Manage fix position under relative div

Tags: html, css

Facing some difficulty for managing some fixed position

Here is my layout

```
|---------------------------------------|
|Breadcrumb (fixed)                     |
|---------------------------------------|
|image(fixed) | Info(fixed)             |
|             | b1/b2/b3                |
|---------------------------------------|
|             | <p>content...........   |
|             | .....................   |
|             | .....................   |
|             | .....................   |
|             | .....................   |
|             | .................</p>   |
|---------------------------------------|
```

Main outer layer position is relative.
**Breadcrumb, Image, Info** these 3 will be fixed only **content** will be scrollable.

- Breadcrumb is under **container-fluid** bootstrap class.
- Image, Info and content are under **container** bootstrap class.

Any Help how to manage this fix div with responsiveness.

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/fjanroid/426uw1fh/1/

**Application Framework**: Angular,

**CSS Framework**: Bootstrap 4.

Comment: There's no `position: fixed` in your css.

Comment: @NicholasOkonneh, Yes, I know I just do the HTML structure with basic CSS.

Comment: So what, really, are you asking?
Maybe you should use css grid or flexbox to make it change in different screen sizes.
Also, do you know how to use media queries?

Comment: @NicholasOkonneh, my first issue how to make breadcrumb, info and image need to be fixed. only content are need to be scroll.If I add fixed position then all the other element are overlap. and add width in  px.

Comment: When using position, you can make use of `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom` in your css to shift them accordingly. Also, add z-index to move them above the other elements on your page. See https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp for positioning reference. You'll find the properties close to the bottom of the page.

Comment: @NicholasOkonneh, might I am making mistake I done all these, but I can do the fix position for image and info section but how to make the breadcrumb section wiith fixed position also? once I scroll down the page the breadcrumb move up.

Comment: Using your fiddle, I made the breadcrumb section fixed by doing
`position: fixed;
z-index: 2;`

Comment: `.bgc{
  background: pink;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0px;
}`

Comment: if you plan to make anything responsive don't use fixed elements. If you update your question with how it is supposed to work it would be easier to pitch in with alternatives.